# How to add a cell reference from another cell in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

I would like to add cell reference in a formula from another cell of the current worksheet. In the above picture, I would like that "8" of "A8" should be referenced from "B4" of the "Sheet1" worksheet. So if there would be "9" or "2" or whatever in "B4", that digit would be added with "A", so it would be "A9" or "A2" instead of "A8".

How to write the formula to achieve that?

Comment: Check out the indirect() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indirect() function and pass arguments concatenate("A",cell value)

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B4),1)
```

[image]